# Social login with HybridAuth

Tags: php, authentication, hybridauth

I'm using [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) to do a social login with Facebook.

I'm getting successfully the **displayName** and **photoURL**. But, the **email** is returning empty. Is there some configuration that I need to do at Facebook Developers Page?

Answer (score 0):

The default scope doesn't return email anymore, but you should configure that you want email returned in HybridAuth configuration, not FB Settings.

FB Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-email

HybridAuth config.php:

```
"Facebook" => array(
    "enabled" => true,
    "keys" => array("id" => "x", "secret" => "xxx"),
    "scope" => "public_profile, email",
    "trustForwarded" => false
),
```

Comment: I'm sure this works, cause I've got it like that on numerous places, so the problem must be elsewhere. Maybe you're just querying a FB account that has no email address associated, as if the person registered through its phone number. Did you try with someone else?

Comment: I've tried with 3 different accounts, and I'm sure these accounts has an email address associated.  
I get de user profile with this:  
    $user_profile = $authProvider->getUserProfile();  
And I'm debugging looking at:  
    $user_profile->email

Comment: Like this? ```$hybrid_auth = new \Hybrid_Auth($hybridAuth_config); $adapter = $hybrid_auth->authenticate('facebook'); $profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();```

Comment: Yes, like this way. And I'm getting this 3 items: identifier, displayName, photoURL.  
I tought I was doing something wrong, so I even bought a ready code at codecanyon, but I got the same problem.  Because of these many tests returning always the same result, I was thinking if I should configure something at FB Developers Page.